# Developer Edition - Salesforce Keeps Navigating To Salesforce Classic

Tags: lightning-web-components, json, error

I don't know why my Salesforce Developer Edition keeps directing to Salesforce Classic and getting those errors: `DevTools failed to load source map: Could not parse content for https://xxx.my.salesforce.com/javascript/1671005676711/sfdc/source/ChatterDefer.js.map: Unexpected end of JSON input`

Scenario: I created a Lightning Component and added it to Home Page.

I tried:

- Deployed it to different Org (I thought one of the Org was broken).
- Removed everything related to Apex method => My code is pure LWC.

Below are my codes:

HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Search Record Type">
        <div class="slds-p-around_medium lgc-bg">
            <lightning-input type="text" label="Enter some text" onchange={inputHandler} value={inputValue}></lightning-input>
        </div>
        <lightning-button label="Search" onclick={handleClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
export default class SearchRecordType extends LightningElement {
    @track inputValue = 'ABC';

    inputHandler(event) {
        this.inputValue = event.target.value;
        console.log(this.inputValue);
    }

    handleClick() {
        console.log('click');
        console.log(this.inputValue);
    }
}
```

Meta.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>55.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: Can you also post the `.js-meta.xml` file? Apart from the class name `lgc-bg` (post the `.css` file too if there is one) I don't see anything unusual in your component. The `ChatterDefer.js.map:` messages are warnings not errors.

Comment: @KeithC I added it. It's just a regular one. Thank you so much.

I don't have .css for this LC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why it happened.

Salesforce will auto-refresh and display in Salesforce Classic when we try to delete/modify setup data (Account, Contact, Opportunity) from free sign-up Developer Edition.